# I need help buiding a HV capacitor circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I want to build a circuit to use this[HV power supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JVJDEZE) to charge up 4 of these[HV capacitors](http://www.ebay.com/itm/291095298708?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT). I do not know how to size the resistors needed. I also want a way to check the voltage with a multimeter to keep from over charging the caps. I plan to make a trigatron to fire the caps. The caps are in series with bleeder resistors and need to be charged to 4.5Kv.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXxJqm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Multimeter for 4Kv? Do you have such a thing?

Comment: We need a close reason "if you need to ask basic things about kV circuits here, then you should not be doing it"

Comment: I would not trust a $6.69 **400kV** transformer from amazon, even if it has 0 current capacity. Also violates rule #1 , *no datasheet = no sale*

Comment: Amazon and eBay components, this has imminent disaster written all over it...

Comment: @carsic It's a DC/DC converter of unspecified topology. And has some stilted English in description (as well punctuation/capitalization issues) so... Wun Hung Lo made or something like that. Amazon seems to let anyone sell anything on their site these days.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff true, I assumed the schematic matched the parts link.

Comment: @crasic: On a question like this? LOL.

Comment: With all due respect, grantr, you need to stop this. Now. Using a 400 kV source to charge caps to 4.5 kV is just crazy - and I don't mean that in a good way. Among other things, if you think that eBay supply is remotely safe you have just qualified for a Darwin Award. 400 kV will simply not see that wire insulation so you are almost certain to get zapped, and your 9 volt battery will never provide 2 to 5 amps.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, it should be covered by a more generic "you are going to kill yourself" reason. Luckily, such users usually only post one question before they disappear from the site.

Comment: the resistors aren't your average ¼W resistors either. Mind you that in kV range the dominant spec of a resistor is it's maximum voltage which is most of the time not listed on ebay/amazon/ali/..., not its maximum power. When I worked with resistors in kV range, after soldering these were carefully potted in a perspex (looking or similar) container before use.

Comment: Ok,The mulitmeter will need to be connected to a voltage divider in order to read a reference voltage.The circuit will be used to explode the bridge wire so the pulse needs to be fast and powerful. That is the reason I chose those caps. The same caps have been used with success.

Comment: Ok that is why I am asking before doing. So the chaepo power supply is out. Where can i find a 4kv dc power supply or schematics to build one? The mulitmeter will need to be connected to a voltage divider in order to read a reference voltage.The circuit will be used to explode the bridge wire so the pulse needs to be fast and powerful. That is the reason I chose those caps. The same caps have been used with success.

Comment: Construcion technique is critical to making high-voltage devices work. Find someone locally to help mentor you, this isn't something you can safely learn on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DC/DC converter really outputs 400kV (hmm), did you realize your caps (in series) are only rated for 4x1300V = 5.2kV max? And I hope you have 400kV rated insulators and resistors too (let me see if I can find an image of something like that).

Anyway, an eerily similar converter sold on 
http://mklec.com/modules/power-modules/dc-3.6v-6v-boost-step-up-high-voltage-generator-module says

> Output Voltage: 1KV+ (manufacturer claims 400KV, however this is unverifiable)

So [amusingly] you'll probably be okay with those caps. As for

> I do not know how to size the resistors needed.

Neither do I... because you have said nothing about the purpose of the circuit or desired time constants (for charge/self-discharge).