# High voltage boost converter safety

Tags: dc, boost

If two standard 1.5V batteries are connected in series (3V), and then the voltage is stepped up using a boost converter to 700kV, is there any danger of burning or electrocution, given the incredibly small output current?

Comment: Have you actually made your 700Kv

Comment: I've ordered one.

Comment: You "ordered" a battery powered factor 233-thousand booster that doesn't break down above 1kV?

Comment: @Asmyldof: It's probably something like http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/195688/54580

Comment: @Asmyldof: first hit in goog https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6R8ONihgwA What's a couple orders of magnitude between friends? And [2nd hit](http://www.amazon.com/Yosoo%C2%AE-700000V-Step-up-Voltage-Transformer/dp/B00T2PNW2W) is indeed one like the other question.

Comment: I'm keen to test it; it does seem a massive boost. Time will tell.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Excellent-DC-3-6V-6V-700KV-Boost-Step-up-Power-Module-High-voltage-Generator-SE-/131387671645?hash=item1e9750c45d:g:0mgAAOSw7ThUm65j Here's a similar sort of item; how correct would you suggest it is? And if, hypothetically, it worked, how would you rate its safety?

Comment: I can't find any 700kV transistors or diodes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a boost converter that cannot exist given the output voltage rating.

Comment: The requested information should be in the datasheet, your guess about "correctness" and "safety" is as good as ours without it.

Answer (score 4):

You can draw a maximum of about a watt per standard (AA) battery. I cannot think of any topology that will generate 700kV using 2 watts of continuous power.

If you could, then the current available would be too low to cause damage, and the power available too low to cause heat problems that you couldn't save yourself from with reflexes.

However, to actually generate 700kV would require some form of energy storage on the low voltage side, and automatically cause storage on the HV side, just because of geometry. Even 10pF of output terminal would store 2.5J.

I have often speculated on doing just this kind of step up. It requires emptying a couple of AA batteries over the course of half an hour or so to charge up perhaps 300v of caps, which are then used to run a tesla coil for a second. Needless to say, the energy available is now lethal, and deserves all the respect that you would accord to a mains driven device.

Comment: https://youtu.be/RtlYi1yLTVQ?t=18 :D